# Android with Robospice: GET request with Json data

Tags: android, json, http, robospice

I develop an Android app with Robospice. The exchanges from my mobile app to my remote server are based on Json (Http GET and POST) for the requests AND the answers.

So I created a JsonSpiceService like that :

```
// @see https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide#wiki-create-a-spicerequest-and-a-listener
public class JsonSpiceService extends SpringAndroidSpiceService {

    @Override
    public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application)
            throws CacheCreationException {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        JacksonObjectPersisterFactory jacksonObjectPersisterFactory =
                new JacksonObjectPersisterFactory(application);
        cacheManager.addPersister(jacksonObjectPersisterFactory);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // find more complete examples in RoboSpice Motivation app
        // to enable Gzip compression and setting request timeouts.

        // web services support json responses
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
                new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter =
                new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter =
                new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters =
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

        listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);

        // @see http://sapandiwakar.in/eofexception-with-spring-rest-template-android/
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()); 

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

My GET request:

```
public class GetDevicesRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<DeviceList> {

    public GetDevicesRequest() {
        super(DeviceList.class);
    }

    @Override
    public DeviceList loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("bla bla bla"); 
        return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url.toURI(), DeviceList.class);
    }
```

This request is send with the standard service JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService :

```
protected SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(
            JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.class);

spiceManager.execute(request, new GetDevicesRequestListener());
```

My POST request:

```
public class SetKelvinServiceRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<RequestGenericResult> {

    @Override
    public RequestGenericResult loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

        KelvinService service = new KelvinService(this.service, this.value);

        URL url = new URL("bla bla bla"); 

        return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url.toURI(), service,
                RequestGenericResult.class);
    }
```

This request is send with my extend service JsonSpiceService:

```
protected SpiceManager spiceJsonManager = new SpiceManager(
        JsonSpiceService.class);

spiceJsonManager.execute(request, new SetKelvinServiceRequestListener());
```

It works when I want to send a request with Json data (POST). But it doesn't work when I send GET request; the result received is always null (my Json deserialization). For my GET request I must use the standard service : JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService

But I don't know why my JsonSpiceService doesn't work with GET request ...

Thank you guys !

Comment: can you add the code that you use to send get requests ?

Comment: We need to see the pojo DeviceList and the Json for that. That's not a RoboSpice problem but a Jackson or Gson problem, depending on the JSON library you use.